# Why is my inherited Espresso class's overridden method (getDescription) in the default constructor not being recognized?

Tags: polymorphism

I'm trying to overload the method getDescription() in the inherited class Espresso, but when I call it in main(), Unknown Beverage is listed and the default constructor in the Espresso class doesn't seem to be getting called.

I want it to print out Espresso Coffee from main() using this extended class.

```
class Beverage        
{

string description;

public:      
Beverage() : description("Unknown Beverage"){};     
string getDescription() { return description; };   
};



class Espresso : public Beverage    
{    
public:    
Espresso() { getDescription() = "Espresso Coffee"; };     
~Espresso();    
};      



int main()      
{      
Beverage *beverage =  new Espresso();          
cout << beverage->getDescription();       
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getDescription() = "Espresso Coffee";
```

doesn't change the `description` member. It returns a new string which you change.

You need a setter method in the base class:

```
Espresso() { setDescription("Espresso Coffee"); };
```